# Can't use images in a folder in Eclipse without manually refreshing the project first

Tags: java, angular, spring, eclipse

i'm doing a project in Eclipse using Angular on Front-End and Spring on Back-End, it is a simple form where the user upload a picture.
The pictures are saved in a folder outside the project, there's a symbolic link of that folder in Eclipse.

The problem is that when i want to see a recap of the form, the symbolic linked folder is still empty if i not refresh it manually.
What can i do to fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using Linux.

Comment: The Workspace preference page has an option to "Refresh using native hooks or polling." Try enabling it.

Comment: @nitind Done, nothing changed, unfortunately. I'm on Linux.

Comment: So you are talking about a Linux symbolic link. Does an [Eclipse Linked Folder](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm) work instead?